# "Pentium-safe FDIV" ... in year 2014?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, cpu

Everytime I look in the compiler settings, the same question comes into my mind: Why does the current compiler of Delphi still have the "Pentium-safe FDIV" compiler option?

The Pentium-FDIV-Bug was found in November 1994 and did not occur in CPU models of 1995. Processors at this time were probably only strong enough work with Windows 95, 98 and maybe also Me. As far as I know, the first Intel Pentium 1 CPU with 133 MHz (and therefore fast enough to reach the minimum system requirements of Windows 2000) was released in June 1995, without FDIV bug, of course.

The VCL/RTL of current Delphi versions makes use of Windows APIs which are not available in ancient Operating Systems. Windows 98 and Me do not work with an empty Delphi XE6 VCL application; I didn't check if the VCL/RTL of Delphi XE6 has already broken Windows 2000 compatibility, but I think so.

So, why does Embarcadero keep a compiler switch which was used in 1994, when they drop support for Operating Systems which were used in year 2000? Ergo, nobody will require this compile option, since the affected CPUs won't be compatible with the Operating Systems the VCL/RTL requires anyway.

**Update**; To clarify the question: Is there any use-case where this switch might be useful? Or maybe the compiler internally ignores the option, and it is just there to preserve the options for old project files?

Comment: Generally you don't break backward compatibility. When the work amount to remove a feature is larger than keeping it, there is no incitament for the effort of removing it.

Comment: @LU +1. I think if you post it as answer, it should be accepted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pentium divide bug affected a number of the very early Pentium models. The highest clock speed of the affected models was 100MHz. The official documents indicate that Delphi XE6 targets Vista and up, but in reality it is still possible to target Windows XP, and I believe that XE6 can make executables that run on Windows 2000. The minimum requirements for XP are a 233MHz processor, and for Windows 2000 a 133MHz processor.

So, it is just about plausible that you might be able to run code compiled by XE6 on a defective Pentium processor. In reality, nobody at Embarcadero, for at least the past 15 years, will have felt any obligation to support defective Pentium processors. They simply have not been seen in the wild in the 21st Century.

So, why has the compiler feature not been removed? Only Embarcadero know the answer to that but I can give a few obvious reasons:

1. Removing the feature disturbs backwards compatibility. If there are people that, even if they don't need to, build with the switch enabled, then removing it will affect them.
2. Removing the feature costs. Doing so involves changes to the UI, the compiler, the documentation, the test suite, etc.
3. Removing the feature introduces risk. Any time you change code, code that is tried and tested over many years, you run the risk of introducing a new defect.

Comment: There's another aspect of backwards compatibility: any code that explicitly says "I don't care about old Pentiums, disable this option" would *also* fail if the option is removed.

Comment: Well, it's funny they will probably try to remove features like GetMem() or Pointers before removing that old, outdated, useless option... is someone relies on having it active for actual code - twenty years later flwaed Pentium was delivered, well, he or she deserves any issue that can arise in his or her code...

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for an "official" answer, you're unlikely to get one. Unofficially, I can certainly point you to David's answer. His 3 points about the reasoning are clear. Unless there is a *compelling* reason to remove the feature, it doesn't make much business or technical sense. About the only reason it should be removed would be if the x86 back-end were completely rewritten from the ground up... in which case it's not so much as removed, rather it simply would not be taken into account in the first place.

I will note that the new AMD64/ia64 and LLVM-based ARM back-ends do not do anything with that directive since it should be axiomatic that those CPUs aren't effected. The directive/option is recognized, but merely ignored.

Comment: Compelling reason? It makes the compiler look twenty years old... if you're not going to remove it from code, at least hide it and leave it disabled. Meanwhile, improve Delphi support for anything released after Windows 95... a lot of code still doesn't use API newer than Windows NT (look at services implementation...)

Comment: *Any* change introduces risk. If it's not really hurting anything, why even bother? Resources are not infinite, so should we not be spending that time on other things?

As for supporting newer Windows features, there is nothing stopping you from digging in an defining the APIs and calling them yourself. No need to wait for a new release for them.

Comment: @Bauer: sure, any changes introduces risks, so to avoid risks the Delphi compilers is stuck in a time bubble created twenty years ago. Also if I have to call API myself because Delphi VCL frameworks is also stuck in the same time bubble, I could do it from C/C++ much easier than from Delphi, at least I've not to translate headers every time. We *do* pay for Delphi also because we do expect someone keeps update both the compiler and the framework - takinf some risks, if needed. Your resource are finite in the sense you have now very finite skills and no longer able to improve.

Comment: Well said from someone without any idea of what they're talking about. FTR, the latest release *did* add some more Floating point optimizations for x86 which was a risky thing to do. The compiler has seen generics added, inlining, x64, ARM, etc... added over the years. So what was that about not taking any risks? 

So you're willing to toss out an entire project so you don't have to declare a couple of new APIs in order to call them? Hyperbole much?

Eventually the axe will be gone if you keep grinding it...

Comment: @Bauer: it looks your developers have no longer any idea about what they working on. When software becomes "untouchable" because nobody knows if something can go wrong if someone does it, it's clear nobody in the company understand the codebase any longer. We all know the issues with generics which plagued several version, the bad floating point codegen in XE6, etc. etc. It's clear the compiler is in the wrong hands. Keeping old, outdated code inside the compiler instead of cleaning it will just grow an even messier code. That explain why Delphi native code is not on par with others'

Answer (score 0):

Delphi still alows making of console applications. And unless your console application relies on newer windows API you could easily make it compatible with Windows 95.

Comment: The fact that Delphi supports console applications (which is a fundamental feature that will never be removed) is not relevant. A default, empty Delphi XE6 project links, with load time linking, to the Unicode API. So it will only run on Windows versions with Unicode API. That means NT based systems. In fact I think that there are a number of other linked APIs that are not present on Windows 95. Windows 95 is not up to the job of running a modern Delphi executable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right. I just did a litle testing and it seems that even console applications made with newer versions of Delphi require athleast Windows 2000 as they call certain functions from kernel32.dll which aren't present in older versions of kernel32.dll like getting OS default language (multilanguage applications support). So my claim from above for being able to make console application with newer versions of Delphi which will run on Windows 95 is false.

Comment: It is documented: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/frequently-asked-questions and it really has nothing to do with console applications

Comment: Console applications are fully native Windows applications linking the Windows API - just without a GUI - remember! They are not "DOS" applications. Windows itself relies on console applications to perform several low-level tasks, and on server you can run Windows just with a console active, no shell, no GUI apps. If Delphi removed console applications, it would become a far less powerful Windows development tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is just hearsay, but apparently the Delphi compiler is written in assembly and basically unmaintainable. They don't remove any features simply because it's incredibly hard to do any kind of change in the compiler so they don't bother.